# How to convert a binary classes column to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have an array like this as the label column (2 labels : 0 and 1) , for example:

```
[0,1,0,1,1]
```

Supposed that I want to convert this array to a numpy matrix with the shape (5,2) (5 elements, 2 labels) . How can I do that in a trivial way by using any util library?

The outcome I want is like this :

```
[[0,1][1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0]]
```

Comment: You want to add the other label (0 to 1, and vice versa)?

Comment: I want to ask if there is any trivial way to do this, because creating a new 2 dimensions array, go through each element, put 1 if existed 0, put 0 if existed 1 is a little bit complicated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a[:,None] != np.arange(2)).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [7]: a = np.array([0,1,0,1,1])

In [8]: (a[:,None] != np.arange(2)).astype(int)
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0]])

# Convert to list if needed
In [14]: (a[:,None] != np.arange(2)).astype(int).tolist()
Out[14]: [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: thanks , this is what I want , took me some hours to search for this :)